# Disable any "pop3-login" on Dovecot

Tags: dovecot

Using Ubuntu Server I have a test-server that sends out mails in PHP scripts. Other than that, it does not do anything with mail. However, I have a bunch of "pop3-login" processes going on. It appears to be somebody/something is trying to login to the pop3 mailboxes. But no POP3 mailboxes are (or should be) working. Is there an easy way to turn off pop3 (or imap) logins for Dovecot? I only need outgoing mails in PHP...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use imap or pop3, then remove dovecot:

```
sudo aptitude remove dovecot dovecot-pop3d dovecot-imapd
```

Dovecot has nothing to do with your outgoing mail, you're probably using postfix, exim, or some other MTA for that.

If you want to use IMAP but not POP3, then just remove the dovecot-pop3d backage. If you want POP3 but not IMAP, just remove dovecot-imapd.

Comment: This is not entirely true, as Postfix may also use Dovecot for SASL authentication. https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your /dovecot.conf file, search for the below parameters or add them if they are not. Then delete the services you don't need or comment it out all together.

```
# Enabled mail protocols.
#protocols = pop3 imap sieve lmtp
```

Answer (score -2):

I set the option 
**login_max_processes_count = 0** 
in dovecot.conf. So far it's working.

Comment: -1 This is a really bad idea. Dovecot is not SMTP software and should not be running or installed if you don't need it. If there are any security vulnerabilities in the software, you're leaving the door wide open for absolutely no reason.